# Custom Margins and Restraints for Individual UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I have a 2-item UICollectionView with Two Cells. My goal is that each time you swipe, at any given time, you will see only an individual cell that is spaced from the margins from left and right equally. If the cells are also different sizes, that must mean that each cell must have individually unique constraints from the margin.

Questions:

1. How do I go about adding constraints to these cells so that they remain evenly spaced across multiple iPhone layouts?
2. How do I make sure that a cell does not "bleed" to the next, making sure that ay ant given time, a single cell is seen on the screen?

[image: Here is my current]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You've to implement three methods in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to make it work right.

1. `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`
2. `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat`
3. `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat`

Return calculated values to each of these and the cells will layout correctly. Here is a sample implementation.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let spacing: CGFloat = 16 * 2
        return .init(width: collectionView.frame.size.width - spacing, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { 16 }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { 0 }
}
```